# Accidentally deleted my /etc/init.d folder from system

Tags: ubuntu, init.d

I know this is really bad,  but i have accidentally deleted init.d folder from my system. I am using VMWare player to load ubuntu 14.04 LTS now my system is not starting properly...:( 
I don't have CD to boot from?
Can anyone tell me how to get this file back by any means?

Comment: Posting this to "Ask Ubuntu" would give you better answers. StackOverflow is for programming and code related questions.

Comment: thanks david i did that too...